# How can I match "snake_case" automatically when I search for "snake-case" by mistake?

Tags: isearch

I frequently mistype "_" as "-" when doing a quick `isearch-forward`.

E.g. I'm looking for `snake_case` and accidentally type <kbd>C-s</kbd> `snake-case` and get no results. Best case I notice quickly enough and don't have to delete too much of the search term, worst case I basically have to type it over again.

Is there some way to hook into `isearch-forward` to change my query into a `isearch-forward-regexp` like `snake[-_]case`?

I need to actually search for `lisp-case` often enough that simply changing "-" to "_" is going to cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: You can avoid typing the whole thing again. Do `M-e` to jump to the mini-buffer to edit the search string while isearch is active. Then `C-e M-b BKSPC _` and `C-s` to continue search.

Comment: By using a more modern, fuzzy matching search 'engine', you simply type 'sc' and snake-case, SnakeCase and snake_case all match (use ido together with flx or somesuch for example)

Comment: @TomRegner How do you do 'flex' search in `isearch`?

Comment: @kaushalmodi bitbucket.org/jpkotta/flex-isearch might do

Answer (score 8):

I can't imagine any such automated behaviour not then causing you pain when that's *not* what you wanted it to do.

To my mind kaushalmodi's recommendation of <kbd>M-e</kbd> is the best answer -- making it easy to correct the problem seems preferable to trying to make isearch read your mind.

Note that isearch is smart enough to take note of the first character where the search failed, and <kbd>M-e</kbd> places the cursor at that position automatically so, even when you've continued to type subsequent characters, the typical key sequence to fix the pattern and resume searching would just be:

<kbd>M-e</kbd><kbd>C-d</kbd><kbd>_</kbd><kbd>C-s</kbd>

Comment: That's awesome! TIL: *isearch is smart enough to take note of the first character where the search failed, and `M-e` places the cursor at that position automatically*

Comment: I didn't know about `M-e`, that certainly makes things easier, especially since it jumps back to the typo.

Answer (score 5):

If you use [swiper](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper) and search for `snake case`, it will match
both `snake_case` and `snake-case`.

`swiper` is a new `isearch` alternative that gives you an overview in the minibuffer as you search.

[image: swiper.png]

In the image above, the input is `ivy m` that translates to the regex `ivy.*m`.
There are 36 matches for this regex. You can navigate between them with <kbd>C-s</kbd>/<kbd>C-r</kbd>
or <kbd>C-n</kbd>/ <kbd>C-p</kbd>.

You can install `swiper` with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-install`. It's available in both MELPA and GNU
ELPA.

Comment: swiper (and swiper-helm) are neat. I've added them to my setup and am trying them out for a few days. Not quite what I was after though as I'll have to type something different than what I'm searching for, will see if I get used to that.
Also, any idea how to get C-w and M-e work while in swiper mode?

Comment: What are `C-w` and `M-e` supposed to do? You can post at https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues if you want me to add something.

Comment: M-e is described in the comments and other answer - it edits the search in the minibuffer. C-w expands the search term with the symbol under the cursor.

Comment: OK, you don't need `M-e` for swiper, it's already in `M-e`. And to get the thing at point, press `M-n`. There's no way to expand it yet, but you can just continue typing.

Comment: M-n is what I was after, that's good to know. The useful feature M-e is that it moves the point to the first non-matching character, I don't know if that's practical with the fuzzy matching though.

Comment: The way swiper works, is that you start out in `M-e`. So any time you mistype, you can simply use `DEL` or `M-DEL`. Both your buffer and the minibuffer try to keep you informed when you've mis-typed.

Comment: I understand that, but it just gets back to the original question then: I'm typing fast enough that by the time I realize I've mis-typed I've got to DEL multiple characters. M-DEL almost works in this example: "snake-case" doesn't match, M-DEL goes back to "snake-" so I still have to DEL to get back to "snake" and then type "_case" again.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a big deal. Just re-define `M-DEL` to delete the separator if it's so important for you. It's trivial to do.